# can't open music library through intent

Tags: android, audio, android-intent

i want to select music/mp3 file from android music library by passing an intent.
     i was succesfull for opening audio library in samsung devices but in case of 
     sony experia it is not working and doen't show any exception.

My code is

```
  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i,11);
```

but when i use this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("audio/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Audio "), 11);
```

it creates a chooser and work perfectly but i don't want to use it because it creates one more step in user input.
Please solve my problem.
Thank you.